# Adb creates the error "adb: CreateFileW 'nul' failed: The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

As the title says, ADB shell produces the error "adb: CreateFileW 'nul' failed: The system cannot find the file specified" whilst trying to start a daemon. I'm an android developer and adb is a critical feature for me. how can i fix?

What have i tried already?:

- redownload adb files
- run working adb files, from a usb (tested on another computer)
- install specific drivers for my phone, using midriverinstall.exe (my phone is Xiaomi mi 9t pro)

Any help is much apreciated

Comment: CreateFile() is a windows API call so it probably has nothing to do with stuff specifically on the phone.  If it were me?  I would use the [system internals process monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) with adb.exe to see what is REALLY happening.  It's a PITA to get the filters right but once you do, the answer should be clear.

Comment: Thank you... But a small problem... I have no clue what this program is or how to use it.

Comment: ProcessMonitor is the best way to go. There are plenty of tutorials online how to use it. You are interesting in the file monitoring part. Filter out all non-adb related processes so that the flood of events is reduced. Then check for errors on file access.

Comment: I just ran it, and consulted an it expert with the results... nothing's wrong, so what's wrong?

Comment: You say nothing is wrong? "an it expert" can't help you unless they are an expert win32 programmer.  SOMEWHERE, there is a result OTHER THAN "SUCCESS" when that call to CreateFile() fails.  Process monitor will tell you what failed and show the path it was trying to use.  Filter only adb.  Filter "!= SUCCESS".  Figure out how to filter CreateFile()  Yes, it is a difficult tool to use but once you figure out how to filter, it will be your friend forever.

Comment: BTW, right click on the columns and create filters that way.  Right click "SUCCESS" -> exclude -> Result.  Find your process name, right click it -> include -> "Process Name".  You probably won't even need the CreateFile() event.. but if there is still too much info, find CreateFile -> Include -> operation.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my entire file system where corrupted. a quick reinstallation and everything worked fine again